How i can make Google Sheets IMPORTXML fetch numbers only?
How i can get =IMPORTXML("https://csgoskins.gg/items/gamma-2-case" ; "/html/body/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[8]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]") to fetch numbers only? I am getting " $1.88 ".
I tried to modify the output cell with the =VALUE function.


You may try:
=--substitute(importxml("https://csgoskins.gg/items/gamma-2-case";"//div[8]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]");"$";)


For inbuilt parsing of the currency amount to a number(recommended), provide the proper "locale" argument to IMPORTXML(for eg, "en_US"):
=IMPORTXML(url;xpath;"en_US")

You can check the that the type is number using =TYPE()
